# Using Drizzle ORM, how to increment a field by 1 when inserting a record?

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql, drizzle

I'm developing a React application integrating the `Drizzle ORM` with a `PostgreSQL` database. In my use case, I need to perform a simultaneous insertion of a new entry into the database and increment a specific column named `sku` by `1`. Additionally, if it's the first entry, I'd like to set the default value of sku to `100000`. Is it possible to implement this functionality in a seamless manner?

**Edit:**

I have managed to get it up and running

```
  const [article] = await db.insert(articles).values(newArticle).returning()
  await db.update(articles).set({sku: sql`COALESCE((SELECT MAX(sku) + 1 FROM articles), 100000)`}).where(eq(articles.id, article.id))
```

However, as soon as I pack the whole thing within a transaction, it no longer works. I suspect it is because the line wants to perform an update, but this has not yet been effectively written to the database. Or am I wrong. What is the best way to solve the problem?

```
  const createdArticle = await db.transaction(async (tx) => {
    const [article] = await tx.insert(articles).values(newArticle).returning()
    const [updatedArticle] = await tx.update(articles).set({sku: sql`COALESCE((SELECT MAX(sku) + 1 FROM articles), 100000)`}).where(eq(articles.id, article.id)).returning()

    return updatedArticle
  })
```

Comment: Give us more detailed description

Comment: Instead of inserting and updating the record, why don't you get the max SKU and set it during the insert?